# DC motor temporary speed change with simple Boost Converter

Tags: motor, dc, boost, converter

I would like to know is if it is possible to give a slight voltage change to a dc motor with simple electronic items.  Meaning that the voltage would normally be a set amount (10v) but would either drop or increase slightly at set or random intervals to produce variations in motor speed.

I haven't been able to find any references to this type of implementation and am wondering if it's possible.  Currently the idea is based around a simple boost converter diagram, with possibly a 555 timer chip controlling the switch. To my knowledge of how the circuit works, when the switch is very quickly closed it produces a current build up from the inductor which produces a higher voltage at the cap, which can then be used by the motor for the speed increase. Or is the cap unnecessary?

[image]

I am not sure if I am on the right track or if there are references that I should be referring too. But any help would be appreciated.  I know there are better ways to control motor speed but this is a low cost application and the random/timed speed burst are more for effect then anything else.
Thanks,

Demsey

Comment: How much current?  How much variation in voltage?  Keep in mind that a boost converter can only increase voltage, but it can not decrease voltage.

Comment: The cap is necessary. During "boost" operation the diode conducts several times the normal operating current, intermittently, delivering packets of charge, which the capacitor has to be able to store. You might be better off with a wound-field motor, and decreasing the field current to boost speed.

Answer (score 2):

If you use your 'standard' boost controller from your diagram to *always* control the voltage to your motor, then you could make it work.

Simply put, for 'normal speed' operation, you would want to use 1 duty cycle for the boost converter; then for 'speed boost' you'd simply change the duty cycle (timing).

Of course, the exact timings & component values (cap & inductor) you'll need will depend on the exact 'boosted' voltage you need, and on your motor's total curremt draw; but yes, a rather simple boost converter could accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I agree,  a simply boost converter topology can be used to increase speed.I don't think you need a capacitor as the motors voltage is defined by the speed it is rotating, and hence it looks like a "capacitor"ie it's a voltage source... The speed is increased not by simply increasing the supply voltage but by increasing the current (torque) available and hence it will accelerate if allowed more current to flow into the "voltage source" which is the motor rotating...  So increasing the speed really depends on what current and torque load the motor is experiencing! If it's already drawing more current than your "boost converter" can cope with, then it would be very difficult to add even more current during the "on" cycle to pump up the current in the motor!  hope that helps!

Comment: The OP (original poster) hasn't been back in three years since s/he asked the question!